# Object reference not set to an instance of an object in delete option of my code and another error in update option of my code

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, gridview, data-binding

I have used the following code to delete and edit some values in the gridview, but as i click delete it shows an error:

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object. in line 48 i.e. con.open();
```

Please help me solve it. And when i click on edit and insert values in shown txtboxes and then click update it shows another error:

```
Specified argument was out of the range of valid values. in the line 74 of my code i.e.
   EmailID = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[7].FindControl("EmailID");
```

The code i have used is-

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;

public partial class Admin_viewSalesmanDetails : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    SqlConnection con;
    String strConnection = "Data Source=HP\\SQLEXPRESS;database=MK;Integrated Security=true";
    SqlCommand cmd;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            BindGrid();
        }


    }

    private void BindGrid()
    {
          using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnection))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
            {

                cmd.CommandText = "select * from salesman_details";
                cmd.Connection = con;


                SqlDataSource1.DataBind();
                GridView1.DataSource = SqlDataSource1;
                GridView1.DataBind();

            }
        }
    }
    protected void GridView1_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
    {
        Label EmpID = new Label();
        EmpID = (Label)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[2].FindControl("EmpID");
        cmd = new SqlCommand("delete from salesman_setails where EmpID=" + EmpID.Text + "", con);
        con.Open();
        int k = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
        if (k == 1)
        {
            Response.Write("<script>alert('Employee Deleted Successfully')</script>");
            BindGrid();
        }
        else
        {
            Response.Write("<script>alert('Error Occured While Deleting')</script>");
            BindGrid();
        }
    }
    protected void GridView1_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
    {
        GridView1.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
        BindGrid();

    }
    protected void GridView1_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
    {
        Label EmpID = new Label();
        TextBox PhnNo = new TextBox();
        TextBox EmailID = new TextBox();
        EmpID = (Label)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[2].FindControl("EmpID");
        PhnNo = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[5].FindControl("PhnNo");
        EmailID = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[7].FindControl("EmailID");
        cmd = new SqlCommand("update  salesman_details set PhnNo='" + PhnNo.Text + "', EmailID='" + EmailID.Text + "' where EmpID=" + EmpID.Text + "", con);
        con.Open();
        int k = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
        if (k == 1)
        {
            Response.Write("<script>alert('Employee Updated Successfully')</script>");
            GridView1.EditIndex = -1;
            BindGrid();

        }
        else
        {
            Response.Write("<script>alert('Error Occured While Updating')</script>");
            BindGrid();
        }

    }

    protected void GridView1_RowCancelingEdit(object sender, GridViewCancelEditEventArgs e)
    {
        GridView1.EditIndex = -1;
        BindGrid();
    }


    protected void GridView1_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
    {
        GridView1.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
        BindGrid();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `GridView1_RowDeleting` and `GridView1_RowUpdating` you haven't initialized your `con` and you are trying to open it.

You can either instantiate the connection at declaration or during its usage in the events.

```
public partial class Admin_viewSalesmanDetails : System.Web.UI.Page
{
      String strConnection = "Data Source=HP\\SQLEXPRESS;database=MK;Integrated Security=true";
      SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnection);
```

Or the better approach would be to instantiate it within the [`using` statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) in your events. For example.

```
protected void GridView1_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
{
    Label EmpID = new Label();
    EmpID = (Label)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[2].FindControl("EmpID");
    cmd = new SqlCommand("delete from salesman_setails where EmpID=" + EmpID.Text + "", con);
    using( con = new SqlConnection(strConnection))
    {
        cmd.Connection = con; //here
        con.Open();
        int k = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
        if (k == 1)
        {
            Response.Write("<script>alert('Employee Deleted Successfully')</script>");
            BindGrid();
        }
        else
        {
            Response.Write("<script>alert('Error Occured While Deleting')</script>");
            BindGrid();
        }
    }
}
```

`using` statement will ensure that `Dispose` would be called on the connection, *(which would close the connection as well)*, even if some exception occurs.

Comment: thank you for your valued answers:),....but after i used the using statement...it is showing an error in int k = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); i.e.Connection property has not been initialized....plz help

Comment: @MayuriKoul, initialize the connection property of the command inside the using statement like `cmd.Connection = con;`, modified my answer as well.

Answer (score 0):

Private fields are lost between `PostBacks` - in your events (`GridView1_RowDeleting`) you are using `SqlConnection` without initializing it first.

Add

```
con = new SqlConnection(strConnection);
```

before `con.Open();`